# Can't change user's details with `usermod`, it claims they are still logged in

Tags: usermod

I can't change a user's home directory using `usermod`;

```
[root@server ~]# usermod -d /some/opther/path userfoo
usermod: user userfoo is currently logged in
[root@server ~]$ who
myuser  pts/0        2013-06-17 11:29 (1.2.3.4)
```

As you can see, I am the only person logged in, userfood isn't logged in anywhere.

```
[root@waccoe-web ~]$ ps aux | grep userfoo
root  16724  0.0  0.0 103236   884 pts/0    S+   11:36   0:00 grep userfoo
```

userfoo also has no processes running.

userfoo exists purely for FTP access to the server. I have stopped, started, and restarted the FTP server (ProFTPD) to ensure there are no hanging FTP connections. This server still thinks userfoo is logged in.

How can I either convince the `usermod` command userfoo isn't logged in, or remove any trace of that account being in use? I suppose I could edit /etc/passwd but that seems like working around the problem to me. Or is that infact going ot be OK? I would have thought that if the system believes the user is still logged in, this isn't going to work until all their sessions have been terminated.

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how usermod determines if a user is logged in but you could try and use "lsof" to see if there are any files being held open in the user's home directory.

Comment: Try stopping proftpd, making the change, then starting it.

Comment: @NathanC As I said in the question "I have stopped, started, and restarted the FTP server (ProFTPD) to ensure there are no hanging FTP connections." - If that wasn't clear enough, I have restarted proftpd many times.

Comment: It's clear that you have restarted it. It's not clear whether you tried to make the changes **while it was stopped**.

Comment: @JennyD Ah, I see! Before stopping it, once it was stopped, and after restarting it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of weeks later I compiled a newer Kernel so I had to reboot the box anyway, this was unsolved essentially, but now we can no longer continue exploring this issue.